# Default installation directory for python changed to Arcgis

Tags: windows, python-2.7, development-environment, arcgis, arcpy

My default python path should be `E:\Program Files Extra\Python27`. Ever since I installed `ArcGIS 10.2`, it added a folder there `E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\ArcGIS10`.2.

Yet, in the `ArcGIS` installation I need to specify another installation path `E:\Program Files Extra\Python27.2`, which contains folders `ArcGIS10.2` and `ArcGISx6420.2`.

My environment path variables do not include any `27.2` or `ArcGIS` but when I tried to install executable python module its default installation path is `E:\Program Files Extra\Python27.2\ArcGISx6410.2\` and can't be changed.

When I pip install it goes back to the normal path `E:\Program Files Extra\Python27`. What needs to change to reset the environment properly?

Comment: Can you clarify this? Which path do you want to be the default? Which install is going to the wrong place: the python module with the executable or the pip module?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27" to be the default anywhere. Pip install is using it, but executable which brings up the blue screen installs into the ArcGIS directory of "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27.2"

Comment: Have you checked all of your other environment variables to see if any contain the ArcGIS path? Sometimes there's a PYTHONPATH variable. What's the package that brings up the executable?